# "This device can perform faster." appears even though I inserted external HDD to USB 3.0 port

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, usb-3

I have a 1TB WD My Passport external HDD. It supports USB 3.0 and has an USB 3.0 cable. Whenever I connect it to my laptop, the message "This device can perform faster. This USB mass storage device can transfer information if you connect it to a Super-Speed USB 3.0 port." appears even though I inserted it in my USB 3.0 port.

The driver Renesas Electronics USB 3.0 Host Controller and Renesas Electronics USB 3.0 Root Hub are already installed on my computer. My laptop is an MSI FX420 and has a Windows 7 64-bit OS.

What should I do?

Comment: An older question in this site that is similar: http://superuser.com/questions/414644/your-usb-can-perform-faster

Comment: But the problem is different

Comment: The USB 3.0 connector has two rows of contacts; the high speed contacts sit behind the USB 2.0 contacts.  If you plug in the connector too slowly, the USB 2.0 contacts can be recognized first and the computer sees it as a USB 2.0 device.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this same problem.  I used an application called "usbtreeview" to look at my usb drives.  It showed that the usb 3.0 thumb drive was plugged into the usb 3.0 port but was running at 2.0 speeds.  If the device is running at 3.0 speeds it will have a little "S" next to it for "Super Speed".  If it's running at 2.0 speeds it will have a little "H" next to it for "High Speed".

In my case the fix was to update my "USB Enhanced Host Controller".  I did this by opening the "Device Manager", right clicking one of the listings for my host controller, and then in the "Driver" tab I clicked "Update".  From there I chose it to search automatically and when it finished, it asked me to restart.  Instead of restarting, I tested the usb device and it now worked as it was supposed to.

Note that there were two USB Host Controllers on my device.  The one I chose was called "Intel(R) 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller - 1C26".  But after it worked to fix the problem I had, I decided to go ahead and update the second one using the same method.  This is an Asus U46E laptop that was updated from windows 7 to windows 10.  The old drivers were released in 2010.  The new drivers were released in 2016.

Also note that the actual USB 3.0 Controller is different.  It's a Fresco Logic FL1000 series, but there were no updates available for it.  From what I understand, it is actually the Host Controllers job to decide whether a usb device is recognized as USB 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your driver situation?  MSI provides drivers here [MSI Drivers](http://www.msi.com/support/nb/FR420FX420.html#down-driver&Win7%2064).

Your USB driver should be at [this link](http://download.msi.com/nb_drivers/usb/usb_nec_2.0.32.0_w700.zip) from the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try a different cable or usb 3.0 device. A bad cable or bad connection could lead to a usb 3.0 compatible device falling back to usb 2.0 speeds. USB 3.0 requires more, higher quality wire pairs for communication. If the connections are not good or the cable is damaged it is possible a usb 2.0 signal could still pass even if a 3.0 signal could not.